# OVER_QUERY_LIMIT with places API

Tags: android, google-places-api

I need to use "nearby search" in my app. So I have opened a new api key specifically for Places Api. (the regular Places api, not the Android one) and it worked perfectly for a short time.
However, suddenly I started receiving OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error. I tried replacing the api key with a new one, but that doesn't help. I even tried opening a new project.. still didn't help.

Comment: And you've configured a billing account and checked if the billing account is in good standing?

Answer (score -1):

The reason you are getting that error message is because you have used up all your API requests and passed over your quota

From the Documentation it says: `"OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"` indicates that you are over your quota.

Source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#StatusCodes

Comment: Now Google Maps Platform requires both a valid API key and good standing billing account in your project. If you don't have a billing account enabled the API fails with OVER_QUERY_LIMIT errors.

Comment: @xomena Do I need to have a billing account enabled even if I use a limited version of the Places API?

Comment: @Keselme Yep, the billing account is mandatory. Google has free $200 quota, if your usage is below $200 you won't pay.